# Pentaho rest client with variable url

Tags: pentaho

I'm new to Pentaho and using the Rest Client. I can get the Rest client to work by using generate rows for the url. But then I need to pass part of the result of the json to be part of the url for the next request. I'm not sure how to do this. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that PDI works with streams, you, for each REST request you made, you will have one row as result. You will have as many rows as many requests you do.

I'm not sure if you can deserialize the JSON object directly from the PDI interface, but in the worst scenario, you can use the "User Defined Java Class" to use some external library (like Gson) and deserialize the object.

Then, you can create another variable in the UDJC step and concatenate the attributes you need on the URL string that comes from the last step.

In the other hand you can use "Modified Javascript" to deserialize it and return the attributes you need to then concatenate it with the URL. To use it, just declare varibles inside the code, and then use "Get variables" button to retrieve the available fields to send to the next step.

There are many ways to do it, I suggest you to use the Modified Javascript because it's easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN parse the Json response, just use Json Input a a nex step, and then use XPath to parse the field you want: $.result.the.thing.u.want.